# Organising blog posts by tag/category

Tags: php, wordpress

is there a way where by default it will show my posts in order of newest first. put say if they are looking for a blog post about sports, then they can click on a option that i will position to the side of the page that allows them to show all the sport blog post.

i dont know if this is done by a tag or a category in wordpress. is there a plugin that can help me do this? or perhaps just standard php code?

Comment: Ain't working that adding the post to a category? then you can add "latest posts by categoty" to anywhere you want to show.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By Default The feature is There in wordpress.

1. First Create the categories like sports entertainment etc.
2. Create Your Posts and on the right hand side select the categories which they belong to.
3. Then Go to appearance->menu and add the categories to the menu which you display in your theme.
4. If you want to add it to a side. Then widgets will help.
5. First install the plugin category posts
   http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/category-posts/
   Go to appearance->widgets and add category-posts in the widgets where you want.

Answer (score 0):

Something like the below in your template file will sort it:

```
$args=array(
                      'orderby' => 'post_date',
                      'order' => 'DESC'
);
```

Great reference guides at the WP Codex - http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/query_posts

So:-

```
<?php
                  $args=array(
                  'orderby' => 'post_date',
                  'order' => 'DESC',
                   );
                 $recent_posts = get_posts($args);
                 foreach( $recent_posts as $recent ){

                 ?>
                <?php

                    $mypages = get_post( $recent->ID );
                    $name  = $mypages->post_name;
                    $content = $mypages->post_content;

                ?>
                <?php if(has_post_thumbnail()) : ?>
                    <div class="thumb">
                        <?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?>
                    </div>
                <?php else : ?>
                    <div class="thumb">
                        <img src="aDefaultImage.jpg" />
                    </div>
                <?php endif; ?>
                <p><?php the_date('jS F Y','<span class="date">','</span><br />'); ?>
    <?php echo $content; ?></p>
            <?php } ?>
```